x86 Linux calling convention
According to the Linux x86 calling convention, certain register states are saved by the caller on the stack frame and certain registers by the callee. Some of the generated assembly from clang for C that I have seen explicitly does some of the push and pop. But if I am hand writing assembly, is the application of calling convention implicit of do I as a programmer have to make sure to abide it?
Please ask for details if the question does not make sense.

You need to follow it to call other people's functions. It's a convention, something we've agreed upon. You can ignore it but then you'll only be able to call code you yourself have written

Calling conventions are used to make code written by different people/tools work together. If a function is not used or uses any third party code, you can set your own calling convention for it.

If your code is called from C, you have to follow its convention. Often you can avoid pushing callee saved registers by just not using those. If you write assembly functions that call each other, it is all up to you.

Usually the assembler source code is converted 1:1 to machine code instructions, ie. what you did write is what you will get. The calling convention is just convention, assembler usually does not even know which convention is being used and doesn't implicitly add extra instructions to your routines to enforce such convention. With many assemblers you could achieve some of that by using macros, but that will be again explicit in the source code, like some form of function prologue/epilogue macro being used, ... So YOU have to write code which conforms the convention, if you want to conform it.

Does this answer your question? Should %rsp be aligned to 16-byte boundary before calling a function in NASM?

The title of that seems different, but the body is actually asking basically the same thing you are.
